# Log4j file of springboot application is renamed with '_>>' suffix on ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, log4j

The log file app.log of my springboot application is renamed to 'app.log_>>' soon (1min) after the startup...

Concerning the rolling files, only one is created with the name 'app.log_>>.gz'

My application is deployed in several environnements, all base on ubuntu. Only some are concerned by the problem. I do not see any difference.

Java 11 / Springboot 2.7 / log4j 2.17.1

My log4j2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="app.log" filePattern="app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="./" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="app.*.log.gz">
                        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="15"/>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </async>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</Configuration>
```

There is no obvious difference between  environments and my internet searches were unsuccessful.

Comment: Regarding the 1 minute between rollovers: Spring Boot configures Log4j Core at least twice (at the beginning and one the Spring environment is ready). If you rename your file `log4j2-spring.xml`, it will be used only once, hence the `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` will fire only once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I rename my file to `log4j2-spring.xml` I don't have log any more.  However, I have removed the `<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy>` tag but nothing has changed.